# windows azure management portal is not show any list how much time it take to run

Tags: azure

I am using winows azure 3  month trial account , when i login into management portal it has not been showing any list or option , I want to know how much time it will take to show managment portal first time or Is there any other way to log in to windows azure managment portal

Comment: What do you mean it does not show any list or option? Can you attach a screenshot of what you're seeing on the portal?

Answer (score 0):

You can access the Windows Azure Management Portal at: http://manage.windowsazure.com

If you are hitting the correct URL and nothing is showing up for you, then you might need to upgrade your browser.